# Google Cloud TTS SynthesizeLongAudio No file created

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api

Following the examples in https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/samples/tts-quickstart?hl=en
I was able to reporduce the script and get a TTS recording sent back to me in python.

However I have issues with using the long form service I have trouble with. https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/create-audio-text-long-audio-synthesis

The main issues when I executive the python script is it finishes normally but nothing ever appears in my google bucket. I dont receive any error so I cant tell what the problem is.

I copied the script and put in my project ID, and out put file output_gcs_uri. But I am not sure what to use for location because my google bucket is multi region, us (multiple regions in United States). I tried "us (multiple regions in United States)", "us", "US","US-CENTRAL1", and "global" but I can not get a file to produce in the Google Cloud Bucket.

I also made sure my service accounts had the following permissions. "Storage Object Creator", "Storage Object Viewer".

I would like to think I did something right because I am still able to produce the TTS locally on my computer.

```
`
from google.cloud import texttospeech


def synthesize_long_audio(project_id, location, output_gcs_uri):
    """
    Synthesizes long input, writing the resulting audio to `output_gcs_uri`.

    Example usage: synthesize_long_audio('12345', 'us-central1', 'gs://{BUCKET_NAME}/{OUTPUT_FILE_NAME}.wav')

    """
    # TODO(developer): Uncomment and set the following variables
    project_id = '...'
    location = 'global'
    output_gcs_uri = 'gs://.../output.wav'

    client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechLongAudioSynthesizeClient()

    input = texttospeech.SynthesisInput(
        text="Test input. Replace this with any text you want to synthesize, up to 1 million bytes long!"
    )

    audio_config = texttospeech.AudioConfig(
        audio_encoding=texttospeech.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16
    )

    voice = texttospeech.VoiceSelectionParams(
        language_code="en-US", name="en-US-Standard-A"
    )

    parent = f"projects/.../locations/global"

    request = texttospeech.SynthesizeLongAudioRequest(
        parent=parent,
        input=input,
        audio_config=audio_config,
        voice=voice,
        output_gcs_uri=output_gcs_uri,
    )

    operation = client.synthesize_long_audio(request=request)
    # Set a deadline for your LRO to finish. 300 seconds is reasonable, but can be adjusted depending on the length of the input.
    # If the operation times out, that likely means there was an error. In that case, inspect the error, and try again.
    result = operation.result(timeout=300)
    print(
        "\nFinished processing, check your GCS bucket to find your audio file! Printing what should be an empty result: ",
        result,
    )`
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem as you and I think there is something wrong with the pipes using python, because I ended up using the POST message to get the long audio output and that worked just fine. I went thru their API with a somewhat finetooth comb at https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/tree/main/packages/google-cloud-texttospeech, and there seems to be no difference between v1 or v1beta1, as I've tried them both, or all 3. So, the POST I use is here, https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/create-audio-text-long-audio-synthesis  and it's not exactly clear what to do, but just use the curl command if you're on linux or windows. Then make sure that where you run your commands from you add the previous json file, those are the only 2 things needed, and the longform audio works, I'm certain that the python instance is broken for now.